# How can I verify the integrity of a WAN connection?

Tags: tcpip, wide-area-network, checksum

We have two scanners in our branch office which upload images to the head office via FTP. In the last week, both scanners have started delivering a lot of corrupted images.

I suspect that the problem may be with the WAN link, and that TCP might not be detecting/correcting all errors. Is there any software for Windows that allows me to test the integrity of the connection by sending packets with an embedded CRC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Wireshark on the file server. Collect traffic. Analyze.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Since starting Wireshark this morning, I've already detected several bad TCP checksums.

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a company that manufactured network equipment. We would stress test lines by sending as much UDP traffic as we could across it and measuring what got dropped. That really is only feasible if you directly control both ends of the link. Otherwise you're testing the path between the two endpoints. If you want to rule out the WAN link as the problem, I would suggest you first:

1. Setup FTP to another machine on the
   LAN, if that is corrupted, you know
   it's not the WAN link but rather the
   scanner. If it is clear, that tells
   you the LAN is not the culprit. Next
   setup FTP to another system
   elsewhere on the internet. (At your
   ISP if you can swing it)
2. If it's corrupted again, that's an
   indicator of the WAN, if it's clean,
   it points to further out.

TCP checksum failures doesn't make much sense as TCP is designed to fail if the checksum fails.